# Stretching items in a flexbox with a max-height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a div that has multiple items that I'm trying to display in a row. I want each item to grow to fit the available height. Though for one of the items, I want to set a max-height. Once the max-height is reached, I want it to be centered.

Here's a visualization of the desired behavior -

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div ...>Item 1</div>
  <div ...>Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.item3 {
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

This works as long as the parent container's height is 90px or less. Once the height exceeds 90px, Item 3 becomes top-aligned.

If I set `align-items: center` on `.parent`, that has the undesired effect of Item 3 "shrinking" to fit its content - that is, I still want it to grow to 90px when there's space.

The only "fixed" size I have is that `Item 3` should not exceed 90px. All other heights are dynamic.

How would I go about doing this?

**Edit:**
Clarification on heights being dynamic: The parent div's height is not set, so it grows to fit its "tallest" child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `.item3` `align-self: center` and `height: 100%`.

It acts just like `align-items: stretch` when the height of the `.parent` is smaller than `90px`

#### Edit

If the size of the parent is determined by its children, you may need to change your dom structure for `.item3` to be a nested element, and style its child:

```css
/* For resizing */
.parent {
  border: solid 3px blue;
  width: 280px;
}

.item1 {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* End for resizing */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
}

.parent > * {
  flex: 1;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.item3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.item3 > * {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 90px;
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div class="item3">
    <div>Item 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Resize it ↑ using bottom left corner</h3>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. Since the parent's height is dynamic (not set directly), it's actually determined by the maximum height of its children. As a consequence, setting `height: 100%` on `.item3` does nothing. If I give `Item 1` a class "item1" change your first parent CSS class `.parent` to `.item1`, that demos what I'm seeing.

Comment: Editing my question to clarify this